# Loop to Find Records Matching Search Criteria then cut and paste between two spreadsheets

Tags: vba, loops, copy-paste, string-matching

I am new to VBA and have been searching online and watching YouTube Tutorials but am having trouble writing the code below and getting it to work.
I am working with two spreadsheets in the same workbook.Any help would be appreciated. Please understand that I am a beginner and need some guidance. There is no need for disparaging comments. I have been working on this for over two weeks and just can’t figure it out.

I have a sheet labeled “template” that has a student name in cell A1. The student's name will change but the location of the name will always be in this cell.

In my second spreadsheet labeled “Evaluations” I need to run a loop in column A to find the student name.

If the student name is found during that search, then I need to copy any information in Column AC that corresponds to the rows where the name is found.

Anything that is copied then needs to be pasted into my first spreadsheet “template” in column A row 61-70 and for it to automatically add any additional rows required to fit the rows copied.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
Dim StudentName As String '(StudentName is a unique identifier)
Dim Template As Worksheet '(this is the worksheet I'm pulling data into)
Dim Evaluations As Worksheet '(this is the sheet I'm pulling data from)
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Set Template = Sheets("Evaluation Form Template")
Set Evaluations = Sheets("Evaluations")

'this is where i want to cut and paste to
'getting an error here
 Range("A61:A70").ClearContents

'This is the value I am looking for: getting an error here
 StudentName = Sheets("Template").Range("A1").Value

 'this is the sheet I am searching my value in Column A
 finalrow = Sheets("Evaluations").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row

 'once it runs the loop if the student name was found in Column A then I   need it to copy and paste any information in Column 29/AC
'into my Template sheet in Column A row 61
 For i = 2 To finalrow
 If Cells(i, 1) = StudentName Then
 Range(Cells(i, 29)).Copy
 Sheets("template").Range("A61").End(xldown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecialxlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
 End If
 Next i

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You've declared your sheets but you do not make use of it .

```
Set Template = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Evaluation Form Template")
Set Evaluations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Evaluations")
```

Then write - `Template.Range("A1").Value`
Instead of - `Sheets("Template").Range("A1").Value`

I think you get an error because you haven't specified the sheet:

Write  - `Template.Range("A61:A70").ClearContents`
Instead of - `Range("A61:A70").ClearContents`

2) If the name of student is unique, you should use the `Range.Find` method instead of looping on all the rows. It will be much faster.

> Returns a Range object that represents the first cell where that
>   information is found.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

```
Dim name_rg As range

{...}

' ~ Search name of the student ~
Set name_rg = Evaluation.columns(1).Find(Template.[a1])

If Not name_rg Is Nothing then
   Template.[a61] = Evaluation.cells(name_rg.row, 29)
Else
   MsgBox("No student found")
End If
```

3) At the beginning add the line below, it will make your code much faster

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

4) At the end of your code, clear the memory and turn back the screen update to `True`:

```
Set name_rg = Nothing
Set Template = Nothing
Set Evaluations = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

~ Your code should looks like :

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim StudentName As String
    Dim Template As Worksheet 
    Dim Evaluations As Worksheet 
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name_rg As range

    Set Template = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Evaluation Form Template")
    Set Evaluations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Evaluations")

    Template.Range("A61:A70").ClearContents

    ' ~ Search name of the student ~
    Set name_rg = Evaluation.columns(1).Find(Template.[a1])

    If Not name_rg Is Nothing then
       Template.[a61] = Evaluation.cells(name_rg.row, 29)
    Else
       MsgBox("No student found")
    End If

    Set name_rg = Nothing
    Set Template = Nothing
    Set Evaluations = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Edit :**
In case there is multiple students in `Template` you will need to do a `For Loop` instead of using the `Range.Find` solution. Below the modifications:

```
Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Template As Worksheet
    Dim Evaluations As Worksheet
    Dim Nb_Rows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x, Row as Integer

    Set Template = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Evaluation Form Template")
    Set Evaluations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Evaluations")

    Template.Range("A61:A70").ClearContents

    ' the table in this example starts in A1
    ' please mind that blank lines might cause issues
    Nb_Rows = Evaluations.[a1].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Row = 61 ' first row to input results in Template
    x = 0    ' needed to increment

    For i = 1 to Nb_Rows
        If Evalutations.Cells(i, 1) = Template.[a1] Then
            Template.cells(Row + x, 1) = Evalutations.Cells(i, 29)
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Set Template = Nothing
    Set Evaluations = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to assist me and explain what I was doing wrong. I ran the macro and there is still one issue. How do I get it to copy all the rows in column 29 that corresponds to the student name, not just the first row?

Comment: You're welcome. Did you solved your issue? Sorry, indeed the example I wrote with the `Range.Find` method will only work if the student name is unique in your sheet `Evaluation`. If this is not the case, are all the students name underneath one of the others?

Comment: Your VBA got me most of the way there. However, I have students whose names repeat in Column A because they have more than one faculty member evaluating them. So, for example, Vince appears in Column A 6 times and each faculty made a comment. I need any comments that correspond to Vince to be pasted in row 61 and each subsequent row below that till all comments have been pasted. Not sure if I'm making sense.

Comment: Ok I see, in that case you will need to use a `For Loop` instead of `Range.Find`. I've edited my reply, please let me know if any issues

Comment: I'm getting error code: compile error:syntax error for the line: If Evaluations.Cells(i, 1) = Template.[a1]

Comment: I got it to work! I added Then to the end of that line.

Comment: Again thank you so much! You have been a lifesaver! It would have taken me far too long to figure this out on my own.

Comment: smallwat3r what if I want this code to work on all worksheets within the same workbook? The evaluation Worksheet1 never changes but template Worksheet2 does it's duplicated for however many students there are.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things I can see that might be an issue.  You're setting some variables to the worksheets but you're not using them. For example are you trying to clear the contents in the template sheet like this:

```
Template.Range("A61:A70").ClearContents
```

you can get the student name like this:

```
StudentName = Template.Range("A1").Value
'or shorter version
StudentName = Template.[A1]
```

In your loop which sheet are you looping in:

```
If Evaluations.Cells(i,1) = StudentName then
```

And lastly you shouldn't have to copy, you can set one value equal to the other to populate the cell like this:

```
Template.Range("A61").End(xldown).Offset(1,0) = Evaluations.Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i,29))
```

The take away from this is make sure you fully qualify where you're getting information and where you're sending it.  One last thing, I'm not sure if this is meant to be this way but you're using `Evaluation Form Template` as the worksheet for `Template` but using the name `Template` as the reference in other places.  Should they be the same?